# Orientation from magnetometer data

Tags: get, orientation, euler-angles, magnetometer

I saw lot of topics with the same title but answers are different.

I have a magnetometer in my phone which give me the components of magnetic field in direction of X, Y, Z.

Which of the following angles can be determined using datas of magnetometer?
Roll, pitch, yaw? And how?

Thank you,
Robert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a magnetometer alone convention would say you could calulate pitch and yaw.  Assuming the z axis of the magnetometer points north.  If the device was pointed perpendicular to the north vector then it would be able to calculate roll.  As I understand it.

Answer (score 0):

> Which of the following angles can be determined using datas of magnetometer? Roll, pitch, yaw? And how?

Assuming roll, pitch and yaw to be with respect to the earth's surface, this is not possible.

- One of several problems:

In general, the [magnetic inclination (AKA magnetic dip)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dip) points north at the equator.  But angles downward as one travels north until it points down into the earth at the magnetic north pole. So, if only using a magnetometer, while the pitch of a plane may be zero at the equator, it would increase to 90 degrees as it is flying across the surface of the earth at the magnetic north poll. Such instrument behavior is not very useful to the pilot.

Consider using a magnetometer and accelerometer to derive Pitch, Roll and Yaw. By fusing the data from these two sensors, useful Pitch, Roll and Yaw information can be calculated.  There are a number of articles & papers on the internet which describes how to do this.  [This one](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/ARTICLE_REPRINT.pdf) is from [NXP](https://www.nxp.com/) & [Circuit Cellar](https://circuitcellar.com/).

In short, the accelerometer is used to create a tilt compass.  That is, a compass that works through calculations even if not held in the plane of the local earth's surface.  From these calculations, we can derive Pitch, Roll and Yaw.

Comment: Added this answer as the accepted answer does not take into account magnetic inclination.